# How did Amon deflect bending?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Okay, okay, so past the whole "how does Amon take away bending" schpeel, how in the world does his bloodbending give him the ability to **deflect people's bending attacks**? I've never quite understood or gotten this.

Comment: is this a repeat of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27141/what-evidence-is-there-that-amon-really-used-bloodbending-to-take-away-bending-o)?

Comment: Amon was a water bender, so he could already block or attempt to block any water attack by a bender of less than or equal skill. More importantly he was a blood-bender, so he could by taking control of another person's body, alter their posture, thus affecting their ability to bend correctly, altering their pose could deflect their bending attacks as well.

Comment: To answer your question, @Solemnity, I'm specifically wondering about his ability to dodge and deflect people's bending attacks. Particularly where Tarrlock mentions that "none of [their] attacks will touch [Amon]".

Comment: @JordanThornquest Fair enough.  Questions like these make me want to actually follow this series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Amon](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Amon#Abilities) was a highly talented, extremely well trained water-bender of considerable skill, so in any particular conflict he could already block or attempt to block any water attack by a bender of less than or equal skill.**

More importantly he was a blood-bender, so he could by taking control of another person's body, alter their posture, thus affecting their ability to bend correctly, altering their pose could deflect their bending attacks as well.

[image: Amon bloodbending Mako while already holding Korra.]

*Amon bloodbending Mako while already holding Korra.*

[image: Mako's firebending is disrupted after being captured by Amon.]

*Mako's firebending is disrupted after being captured by Amon.*

In a conflict where he was fighting both Korra and Mako, he was able to hold Korra still, preventing her from using her bending powers. Dodging Mako's fire-bending, Amon then uses his blood-bending to grab Mako, disrupting his fire-bending ability before capturing both of them.

[image: Amon grabs both Korra and Mako with his bloodbending.]

Amon grabs both Korra and Mako with his forbidden bloodbending techniques.

You can see the battle between Amon, Korra and Mako at this [video link](http://youtu.be/EO8mlXg81NY). Start around 1:15 if you want to just skip to the fight...

Comment: Ah, that would make more sense. I was more perplexed about his ability to dodge every attack lobbied at him in the episodes leading up to the reveal that he was a blood-bender. So he simply, subtly alters their stance to disrupt their bending?

I could go with that!

Comment: When people didn't know he was a blood-bender, they would just assume they were missing their attacks because it was a subtle thing. Done right, they wouldn't even realize it was happening.

Comment: This is an excellent observation. I wish they verbally would have touched on this, even just a little bit.